# How to replace Net Framework 4.5 with 4.0?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, .net-framework, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

How can I replace Net Framework 4.5 with 4.0 in Windows 8.1?

So far I can disable and re-enable Net Framework 4.5 on "Turn Windows Features on or off", but I'm unable to manually install Net Framework 4.0 or Uninstall 4.5 beforehand since there is no option to remove it.

Net framework Repair tool doesn't include an uninstall option and the methods [listed here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/uninstall-microsoft-net-framework-with-aaron-stebner-cleanup-tool/) don't affect my Windows 8.1 installation.

What I'm missing?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.0 is not supported on Windows 8.1 and there is no official way to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Hahndorf said:

> NET Framework 4.0 is not supported on Windows 8.1 and there is no official way to install it.

Answer (score -1):

Try .net cleanup tool.
http://techdows.com/2014/05/download-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-2-offline-installer.html
It has been updated from a while to support W8 series and .net 4.5. Be warned that removing .net installation can affect/remove other windows features too. RSAT (Remote Administration Assessment Toolkit), UI things that include Graphical Management Tools and Infrastructure Server Graphical Shell, also PowerShell 4.0 and ISE.

Comment: .ne 4.5 is buildin and can't be removed in Windows 8.x

Comment: It can be removed, but it affects various stuff.

Comment: it can't be removed officially.

Comment: Yes, but officially you cant'd do much in windows, specially since Vista.